# Can not find libtinyxml 2.6.x

Tags: libraries

I'am running ROS on Ubuntu. When I tried to compile a package, errors occured. On the develop page, it suggested that we should update tinyXML to the latest version, which is 2.6.x. I typed sudo apt-get update first and sudo apt-get install libtinyxml on the command line, but I can only find 2.5.x version. I check the official website and make sure that the latest version is 2.6.2.

My Ubuntu is 10.10. How can I install libtinyxml 2.6.2 using apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

To compile packages you need the dev or devel variant.

Version 2.6 is not available in the official repositories. You need to find an unofficial repository or install it manually from the source. It shouldn't be hard for a library like tinyXML that has few dependencies.

Comment: Where can I find the unofficial repository for tinyXML? Thanks

Comment: Well...I found a way to install tinyXML from .deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tinyxml/

Comment: The location you linked is where apt downloads from...

Comment: Yeah, I know. But somehow I can't find and install this package by apt in my Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: it's probably belonging to an ubuntu version newer than the one you're using.